# implementation of low pass filter (in python) for continuous time input function

Tags: python, filter

I am working on cooperative FMCW radar systems. I have two stations separated by a distance and one target. At the station one, I have received reflected echo from station one as well as station two. For the received signal, I have Intermediate frequency signal in time domain.How can I implement low pass filter (in python) for continuous time input function. any thought thanks

Comment: Assuming you have discreet datapoints as input I can recommend you to look into FIR or IIR filters.

Comment: While fascinating, this is way too broad to be answerable. Have you got *anything* already? Will you have to start by hooking up hardware communication to Python at all, or do you have an entire system written in Python already (if so then what?) and just need a small lowpass filter module within that? What exactly is the step you're stuck on in implementing this?

Comment: thanks........I am using these functions ...signal.firwin() and signal.lfilter...but these functions only takes discrete data. that,s why I have aliasing problem.

Comment: Please be a little more specific and describe what you have. "I'm already using some function and have problem X, Y or Z with it" is very different from "where do I start?"

Answer (score 4):

You should take a look at [SciPy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/index.html), in particular the [Signal Processing library](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html). This library allows you to convolve, B-spline, and filter timeseries data. You might need to massage your data into something the library methods understand using [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/).

Learn about installing the [full SciPy stack](http://www.scipy.org/install.html). There are also many scientific Python distributions, including [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads.html):

"Anaconda is a completely free Python distribution (including for commercial use and redistribution). It includes over 195 of the most popular Python packages for science, math, engineering, data analysis."

Good luck!